# How to align views with top and bottom and left and right?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, layout, flexbox

I am trying to create ui designs, Here is my current design:

[image: screenshot]

In this, i Have two views for of rectangle shape, here is my code :

```
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                    <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
                </View>
            </View>
```

The expected , output is the first rectangle should be on top left ( which is looking correct by below image ) and the second rectangle should be at bottom right. But its placing next to the first rectangle.

How to move, the rectangle to bottom right corner ? I tried all, like justify content , with flex end but nothing changing. Please help

Comment: Have you tried `bottom: 0` ?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes, As the second rectangle stays there itself !

Answer (score 0):

Using `Dimensions` will do the trick for you.
Modify your code as below

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View , Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width

export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
      <View style={{ flex:1,flexDirection: 'column', alignContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ width: width/2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' , justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <View style={{ width: width/2 ,  height:100 ,backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
                </View>
            </View>
    );
  }
};

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlexDirectionBasics);
```

Output: [image]

Comment: How to bring the second rectangle to the bottom right of the screen  ?

Comment: @Arvindh please check now !

Answer (score 0):

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between', flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
      </View>
    </View>
```

First you have to set `flex: 1` so it can grow. And second step is to add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` instead of `alignContent: 'space-between'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add flex:1 property to the parents style.
Also the property is called justifyContent and not alignContent

Here is your code corrected

```
<View style={{  flex:1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                <View style={{ width: 100 * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}/>
            </View>
        </View>
```

You can view an example here: https://snack.expo.io/@clemband/funny-cereal